# themify icons and fontawesome icons not showing

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I am creating HTML template which has these icons:

```
<i class="ti-user"></i>
<i class="ti-facebook"></i>
<i class="ti-twitter"></i>
```

although I included themify and fontawesome on the template, no icons are showing.

what should I do, please?
and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For font awesome - It could be a CDN issue. Try getting a CDN from cloudflare. It resolved the issue for me.

For themify - you need to open the "themify-icons.css" and update the folder path for the fonts directory. If the relative path changes, then it needs to be updated in the css file as well.

```
src:url('../fonts/themify.eot?-fvbane');
src:url('../fonts/themify.eot?#iefix-fvbane') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/themify.woff?-fvbane') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/themify.ttf?-fvbane') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/themify.svg?-fvbane#themify') format('svg');
```